# Google Docs: insert newline in find-and-replace results

Tags: google-docs

I want to change lines of this form:

```
one line find text
```

into this a pair of lines of this form:

```
first line of replace text
second line of replace text
```

I know that one can search for a newline by checking the "Match using regular expressions" box, and filling in `\n` in the "Find" box. But `\n` in the "Replace with" box appears to insert `\n` into the results, rather than the desired newline.

I tried using this search-and-replace, but it hasn't worked for me:

```
Find          `one line of find text`

Replace with  `first line of replace text\nsecond line of replace text`
```

My next strategy was to use the regular expression matching construct of a parenthesized regular expression in the Find box and a `$`[number] expression in the Replace with box, but it also didn't work for me:

```
Find          `(\n)one line of find text`

Replace with  `$1first line of replace text$1second line of replace text`
```

Is there a way to do this in Google Docs at all, or must I export to a more capable word processor (such as *Word* or *Libre Office*), do the find-and-replace there, and import back to Google Docs?

*Note 1:* I'm describing Google Docs behavior as of July 2019. It's possible that this is a missing feature for now, but will be a functional feature in the future, which could flip answers between right and wrong (unless they include "as of" qualifiers).

*Note 2:* The question "[Regular Expression Carriage Return Find & Replace on Google Docs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200199/regular-expression-carriage-return-find-replace-on-google-docs)" appears to address a similar question, but it's not worded clearly enough for me to tell whether it's a duplicate. The one answer mentions an "HTML mode", but I don't see such a mode in Google Docs.

Comment: I am not agree with you, the method `text.replaceText('one line of find text', 'first line of replace text\nsecond line of replace text');` works fine making all replacements at once.

Comment: @АлександрЕрмолин, are you suggesting a Google Docs programming feature, as opposed to typing things into the interactive find-and-replace command?

Comment: Right. I mean the programming feature (non-interactive).

Comment: Belongs on https://WebApps.StackExchange.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find & replace commas with newline on Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7528169/find-replace-commas-with-newline-on-google-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 4):

1. In a Google doc, we can find-and-replace each instance of specified text with newline (or other special characters) using Google Apps Script.
2. First, edit the doc.
3. Select menu Extensions->Apps Script. That leads to an Apps Script Editor for a script that will apply only to that single document.
4. For example, to insert a newline after every comma, edit/use the script below.
5. Select Run.

```
    function myFunction() {
      var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument(); 
      var body = doc.getBody(); 
      body.replaceText(',', ',\n');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56857715/google-docs-insert-newline-in-find-and-replace-results#comment100332992_56857715), it is possible to solve this by going to Extensions -> Apps Script and adding something like this:

```
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
var body = doc.getBody();
// remove extra spaces at the end of paragraphs.
body.replaceText('[ ]+$', '');
```

Then click `Run` and have this script run over your document.

**Note** the use of `$` instead of `\n`, which would be the right way to reference the end of the string. Even though this doesn't work when using the Search & Replace built-in function in Docs, it works for Apps Script.

Comment: Unfortunately custom Apps Scripts don't work if you have Advanced Protection enabled on your Google account.